# Configuration parameters in my iOS Static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I have in my static library:
I wish I had a way to add some configuration parameters such as the address of my server:
if there was a static library I would have done it this way:

```
NSString *serverURL =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"kServerURL"];
```

how can I do this in my static library?

Comment: I can't see what you exactly want to do, let alone what the relation to a static library is.

Comment: Include a configuration file with your static library (i.e. a PLIST file) where these values can be accessed / changed by the end user of your library.